# minitest - output better error reporting while the tests are running

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is there an alternative test reporter for minitest that will display what tests have broken and what the error message is, while the tests are running rather than having to wait until the end.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the [minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) gem.  It lets you format your test output in various styles including a spec format that prints the name of each test followed by a PASS/FAIL result.  You just need to add a line to your Gemfile and put the following lines into `test_helper.rb`:

```
require 'minitest/reporters'

Minitest::Reporters.use! [ Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new ]
```